# How do I tell a program where to start reading a .txt file?

Tags: c++, loops, fstream, ifstream, seekg

I want my program to be able to remember where it left off in a `.txt` file in order to proceed to the next input upon reiteration through a loop.
For instance, a text file containing:

```
Apples
Bananas
Oranges
```

would be accessed through a function `GetItem()` that appends the next file input into a vector of items. How do I make the function add `Apples` the first time, `Bananas` the second time, and `Oranges` the third iteration? As of now, each call to `GetItem()` keeps adding the first element to the vector, giving a vector containing:

```
Apples
Apples
Apples
```

Because the file keeps opening from the beginning. Any help would be appreciated.

This is a simplified version of lengthy amounts of code that I could include, but would distract from the main purpose of the question. If the code is needed, I would be happy to include it.

```css
vector<Item*> AddItemToInventory(vector<Item*> inventory) {
if (inptLctn == 'f') {
        inptFile.open("TestFood.txt");
        if (!inptFile.is_open()) {
            cout << "Could not open file." << endl;
            exit(1);
            }
            inptFile >> usrInptName;
            inptFile >> usrInptQnty;
            inptFile >> usrInptExpr;
            inptFile >> usrInptPrice;

            }
prdc = new Produce;
    prdc->SetName(usrInptName);
    prdc->SetQuantity(usrInptQnty);
    prdc->SetExpiration(usrInptExpr);
    prdc->SetPrice(usrInptPrice);
    inventory.push_back(prdc);

    return inventory;
}
```

Comment: Why are you closing the file?

Comment: How about: don't close and open the file every time?

Comment: @Mooing Duck Yes, but when I took out the statement, the same problem occurred.

Comment: @immibis Is there a way to open the file only once, iterate through as many times as needed, and close at the end? Because the file is used in a function call outside main, so each end to the function call restarts the process.

Comment: Please share you code to allow us to make an educated guess. :D and yes or you are closing and opening the file in each iteration or your pointer to the file is not moving...

Comment: @ntjess That's the normal way to process a file, and it happens automatically if you don't close and re-open it.

Comment: use [fopen()](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/22558/) then at the end of the looping fclose... see the __[example](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/22558/#msg118123)__

Comment: You return a vector with only one item. Why not read all the items and return all of them in that vector.

Comment: Change it to `AddItemToInventory(vector<Item*> inventory, ifstream &inptFile)` then have the caller in charge of opening and closing the `ifstream`?

Answer (score 3):

Open the file before you use it and close it after you are done using it. The problem is that you are continually closing the input file so when you re-open it, it starts at the beginning again.

You should only open and close your input file once.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Does this mean I should open and close the file in main?

Comment: Because I run into scope problems doing this :/

Comment: Open yes. It will close itself when it goes out of scope.

Comment: Sure, you can open in main. Then you have to pass the input stream by reference to the calling function. If you pass by value, the copy of the input stream object in the calling function will not have an association with the file.